I got error after I added into model shouldBeStrict The attribute [id] either does not exist error
In Laravel 11 app I have app/Models/News.php model referenced to :
class News extends Model implements Feedable
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'news';

    protected $casts = [ 'created_at' => 'datetime', 'updated_at' => 'datetime', 'published_at' => 'datetime' ];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        if(App::isLocal()) {
            Model::shouldBeStrict(); // ERROR AFTER I ADDED THIS LINE
        }
        static::deleting(function ($news) {
            if (Storage::exists($news->image)) {
                Storage::delete($news->image);
            }
        });
    }


    public function userReactions(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reaction::class, 'model_id', 'id');
    }

and running request using userReactions :
    $this->newsList = News
        ::orderBy($orderByField, $orderByFieldDirection)
        ->orderBy($orderByField2, $orderByFieldDirection2)
        ->with('creator:id,name,slug')
        ->with('newsCategory:id,name,uploaded_file')
        ->with('userReactions')
        ->with('tags')
        ->getByPublished(NewsPublishedEnum::PUBLISHED)
        ->getByCompanyId($this->filterCompanyId)
        ->getByIsHomepage($this->onlyIsHomepage)
        ->getByTitle($this->searchTitle, true)
        ->select('id', 'news_category_id', 'title', 'content', 'slug', 'image', 'published', 'created_at', 'creator_id')
        ->paginate(ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::NEWS_PER_PAGE))
        ->through(function ($newsItem) {
            $newsItem->image = (new CheckModelImage())->get($newsItem->image, get_class($newsItem));
            return $newsItem;
        });

In case I added lines with Model::shouldBeStrict(); in model boot method I got error :
The attribute [id] either does not exist or was not retrieved for model [App\Models\Reaction].

Table reactions defined as :
        Schema::create('reactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');

        $table->morphs('model');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('action');

        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

        $table->unique(['model_type', 'model_id', 'user_id', 'action'], 'reactions_4fields_unique');
        $table->index(['model_type', 'model_id', 'action', 'created_at'], 'reactions_4fields_index');
        $table->index(['created_at', 'model_type', 'model_id'], 'reactions_3fields_index');

Without shouldBeStrict added I have no such error all works ok:
In app/Models/Reaction.php :
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Enums\ReactionActionEnum;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Spatie\Tags\HasTags;

class Reaction extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'reactions';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
//        if(App::isLocal()) {
//            Model::shouldBeStrict();
//        }
    }

    public function scopeGetByModelId($query, string $modelId = null)
    {
        if ( ! empty($modelId)) {
            $query->where($this->table . '.model_id', $modelId);
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function scopeGetByModelType($query, string $modelType = null)
    {
        if ( ! empty($modelType)) {
            $query->where($this->table . '.model_type', $modelType);
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function news(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(News::class, 'model_id', 'id');
    }

What is wrong ?
ADDITIVE CODE :
In models I mentions there are both protected
In News :
$fillable  = [ 'id', 'company_id', 'news_category_id', 'title',  'slug', 'content', 'content_shortly',
    'creator_id', 'is_homepage', 'is_top', 'published', 'image', 'source_type', 'source_url', 'youtube_key',
    'updated_at', 'published_at',
];
protected $guarded = ['created_at']

and in app/Models/Reaction.php :
protected $fillable = ['model_id', 'model_type', 'user_id', 'action'];
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at'];

I use 'id' in $fillable property as seeding data on app init I set news with defined id
News::create([
    'id' => 5,
    'company_id' => 1,
...

I did not show these properties as I did not think that could be the issue.
What is wrong in my properties?
ADDITIVE CODE # 2 :
I found where this error happened. I have summary request like :
$newsTb = (new News)->getTable();
$reactionTb = (new Reaction)->getTable();

// Get more news reactions count grouped by news
$this->reactions = Reaction
    ::getByModelType(News::class)
    ->leftJoin($newsTb, $newsTb.'.id', '=', $reactionTb.'.model_id')
    ->whereHas('model', function ($query) use ($newsTb) {
        $query->where($newsTb.'.company_id', $this->companyId);
        $query->where($newsTb.'.published', NewsPublishedEnum::PUBLISHED);
    })
    ->groupBy('model_id')
    ->orderBy('reaction_count', 'desc')
    ->limit($listingLimit)
    ->select(
        $reactionTb.'.model_id',
        DB::raw('count('.$reactionTb.'.id) as reaction_count'))
    ->get()

which generated sql :
  SELECT `reactions`.`model_id`, count(reactions.id)     AS reaction_count
    FROM `reactions`
    LEFT JOIN `news` on `news`.`id` = `reactions`.`model_id`
    WHERE `reactions`.`model_type` = 'App\\Models\\News'     AND ((`reactions`.`model_type` = 'App\\Models\\Comment'     AND
    EXISTS (  SELECT *
    FROM `comments`
    WHERE `reactions`.`model_id` = `comments`.`id`     AND `news`.`company_id` = 1     AND `news`.`published` = '1'))     OR (`reactions`.`model_type` = 'App\\Models\\News'     AND
    EXISTS (  SELECT *
    FROM `news`
    WHERE `reactions`.`model_id` = `news`.`id`     AND `news`.`company_id` = 1     AND `news`.`published` = '1')))
    GROUP BY `model_id`
    ORDER BY `reaction_count` desc limit 5

As reactions table has morphs field the request does not use id field - that raise error. I suppose as id field is not used to tie 2 fields
a) What rule is it? Please link to it.
b) How can I fix it ?

I would install the laravel-debugbar to see what SQL is actually executed. Does it retrieve the reactions.id column?

@JorisJ1,  I checked and see no. THat is grouping sql like: selectreactions.action, count(reactions.id) as reaction_count from reactionswherereactions.model_type= 'App\\Models\\News' andreactions.model_id= '214' group byaction . How that can be salved ?

Where does the error occur, during the execution of the query? If so, does it work when you try something smaller like $this->newsList = News::with('userReactions')->get();?

@JorisJ1, please read ADDITIVE CODE # 2

What I understand you are trying to accomplish with the query is to get reactions where the model_type is 'App\Models\News', and also add an additional column reaction_count counting reactions with the same model_id.
This is the smallest query that I could write still has the attribute [id] either does not exist... error.
$reactions = Reaction::
    where('reactions.model_type', 'App\Models\News')
    ->groupBy('model_id')
    ->select(
        'reactions.model_id',
        DB::raw('count(reactions.id) as reaction_count'))
    ->get();

Interestingly, the error is not thrown while executing the query but only when trying to access the retrieved model's attributes.
This modification made it work for me. I removed the group-by and instead made use of windowing.
$reactions = Reaction::
    where('reactions.model_type', 'App\Models\News')
    ->select(
        'reactions.*',
        DB::raw('count(reactions.id) over (partition by model_id) as reaction_count'))
    ->get();


Hey @mstdmstd was my answer in any way useful? If not I will delete it.
